# Showing Work Breakdown Structures in Tuleap

Tags: windows, packages

Is it possible to show a Work Breakdown Structure in Tuleap?  It would be nice to see a graphical tree of the artefacts from feature EPICs thought USER STORIES and their resultant TASKS.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a hierarchy in the administration panel that states:

Epic -> User Story -> Task. (note that if you use the agile dashboard template provided with Tuleap you might already have this hierarchy).

Once this is done, I you go to a User story that is referenced by an Epic and at the top, just above the artifact title, you'll find the epic's name.

If you go to an epic and you click on the "children" tab (which appears thanks to hierarchy setting), you'll see all the children user stories and for each one of them, all the children tasks.

I hope this is what you were looking for, if not, please let me know.